# oauth2:custom-grant

Tags: spring-security

I meet this problem when I import the source code of spring-security-OAuth2. I am not quite familiar with XML.

the wrong code is

```
<oauth2:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails">
    <oauth2:authorization-code />
    <oauth2:custom-grant token-granter-ref="tokenGranter" />
</oauth2:authorization-server>
```

it reported

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'oauth2:custom-grant'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2":implicit, "http:// www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2":refresh-token, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2":client-credentials, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/ security/oauth2":password}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Spring Security OAuth that does not support "custom-grant"